# Why is my lawn changing colors?

Tags: identification, lawn

I'm wondering what is causing my lawn to apparently change colors... this a small segment of approximately a 3' x 6' area. There is another smaller area, about 2' x 4' nearby, and while I was mowing yesterday, it looks like some other areas are starting to show.

The blades (leaves?) are actually a little more reddish in color than the image shows.

I am in Southwest Florida (Ft. Myers area).

Any idea what this is and what to do about it (if anything)?

Thanks!

Frank

[red-brown lawn http://www.unkfrank.com/images/StackExchange/lawn031614.jpg](http://www.unkfrank.com/images/StackExchange/lawn031614.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a form of [crab grass](https://www.google.com/search?q=Digitaria%20sanguinalis%20L&client=firefox-a&hs=G4w&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=gycnU8G4I4iF2QXitoG4Cg&ved=0CCcQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=1011)( Digitaria sanguinalis ) or [Dallisgrass](https://www.google.com/search?q=Paspalum%20dilatatum&client=firefox-a&hs=k3w&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=YycnU4I-6KbYBemkgMAG&ved=0CCkQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=1011)  ( Paspalum dilatatum ) which can sometimes turn reddish based on many external growth factors (sunlight, water, temp etc).

A good resource is [this site](http://www.floridalawncare.org/101.html) based on your location.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a paspalum sp. Common native lawn weed in southwest Florida. Typical to turn red color during drought conditions in winter/spring South Florida.